# Unable to run walkFileTree method

Tags: java

My program will walk through the directory and get the exact location of the file. But unfortunately, i am getting `NullPointerException` on the `walkFileTree` method. I tried to print out the `rootDirectory` value and it's able to display.But the exception thrown out from the following line of code

```
Files.walkFileTree(rootDirectory, new FileVisitor<Path>()
```

Here is my sample source code

```
public class DirectoriesMonitoring 
{
   static Path rootDirectory;

   public static void main(String [] main)
   {
       rootDirectory = Paths.get("C:/REST API/source");
       System.out.println(rootDirectory);

       try
       {
           System.out.println(rootDirectory);
           Files.walkFileTree(rootDirectory, new FileVisitor<Path>()
                   {
                    //System.out.println(rootDirectory); 
                    @Override
                    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException 
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException 
                    {
                        System.out.println("The file is : "+file);  
                        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException 
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException 
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return null;
                    }

                });  


       }
       catch(IOException e)
       {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
```

Here is the full stack trace

```
C:\REST API\source
C:\REST API\source
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2699)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2742)
    at DirectoriesMonitoring.main(DirectoriesMonitoring.java:21)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the Javadocs

Controlling the Flow

Perhaps you want to walk the file tree looking for a particular directory and, when found, you want the process to terminate. Perhaps you want to skip specific directories.

The FileVisitor methods return a FileVisitResult value. You can abort the file walking process or control whether a directory is visited by the values you return in the FileVisitor methods:

CONTINUE – Indicates that the file walking should continue. If the preVisitDirectory method returns CONTINUE, the directory is visited.

TERMINATE – Immediately aborts the file walking. No further file walking methods are invoked after this value is returned.

SKIP_SUBTREE – When preVisitDirectory returns this value, the specified directory and its subdirectories are skipped. This branch is "pruned out" of the tree.

SKIP_SIBLINGS – When preVisitDirectory returns this value, the specified directory is not visited, postVisitDirectory is not invoked, and no further unvisited siblings are visited. If returned from the postVisitDirectory method, no further siblings are visited. Essentially, nothing further happens in the specified directory.

Change to

```
 public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir,
                                      IOException exc) {
    System.out.format("Directory: %s%n", dir);
    return CONTINUE;
}
```